# windows XP file open/save dialog and Secondary drive

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-explorer

One of my computers, running Windows XP sp3, has 2 HDDs, 40GB each. Each of them is partitioned into two drives, 20GB each, using FAT32.

Now The standard file open/save dialog does not display the partitions from the second HDDs( the one that does not have the boot partition). Windows Explorer shows all 4. This leads to a complicated workflow and a lot of frustrations. Can you suggest a remedy?

Answer (score 0):

The quickest and dirtiest solution is junction points (hard links) to the root folders of each of the second drive's partitions. But that's dirty and it's a workaround, not a solution.

I would take the time to find out what's causing the problem. Is it permissions? Is it in only one app's Open / Save dialog? That sort of thing.